# C - Segmentation fault using strtok

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fgets, strtok

I have this code where its read multiple files and print a certain value. After reading files, at a certain moment my while loop stop and show a segmentation fault ...

Here is my code

```
int main () {

    const char s[2] = ",";
    const char s2[2] = ":";

    char var1[] = "fiftyTwoWeekHigh\"";
    char *fiftyhigh;
    char *fiftyhigh2;
    char *fiftyhigh_token;
    char *fiftyhigh2_token;
   
    char var2[] = "fiftyTwoWeekLow\"";
    char *fiftylow;
    char *fiftylow2;
    char *fiftylow_token;
    char *fiftylow2_token;

    char var3[] = "regularMarketPrice\"";
    char *price;
    char *price2;
    char *price_token;
    char *price2_token;
   
    FILE *fp;
    char* data = "./data/";
    char* json = ".json";
    char line[MAX_LINES];
    char line2[MAX_LINES];
    int len;
    char* fichier = "./data/indices.txt";

    fp = fopen(fichier, "r");

    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier %s", fichier);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        char fname[10000];
        len = strlen(line);
        if (line[len-1] == '\n') {
            line[len-1] = 0;
        }
        
        int ret = snprintf(fname, sizeof(fname), "%s%s%s", data, line, json);
        if (ret < 0) {
            abort();
        }
        printf("%s\n", fname);
        
        FILE* f = fopen(fname, "r");

        while ( fgets( line2, MAX_LINES, f ) != NULL ) {
            fiftyhigh = strstr(line2, var1);
            fiftyhigh_token = strtok(fiftyhigh, s);
            fiftyhigh2 = strstr(fiftyhigh_token, s2);
            fiftyhigh2_token = strtok(fiftyhigh2, s2);
            printf("%s\n", fiftyhigh2_token);

            fiftylow = strstr(line2, var2);
            fiftylow_token = strtok(fiftylow, s);
            fiftylow2 = strstr(fiftylow_token, s2);
            fiftylow2_token = strtok(fiftylow2, s2);
            printf("%s\n", fiftylow2_token);

            price = strstr(line2, var3);
            price_token = strtok(price, s);
            price2 = strstr(price_token, s2);
            price2_token = strtok(price2, s2);
            printf("%s\n", price2_token);
        
            //printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", line, calculcx(fiftyhigh2_token, price2_token, fiftylow2_token), "DIV-1", price2_token, "test");
            
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is :

```
./data/k.json
13.59
5.31
8.7
./data/BCE.json
60.14
46.03
56.74
./data/BNS.json
80.16
46.38
78.73
./data/BLU.json
16.68
2.7
Segmentation fault
```

It is like my program stop because it can't reach a certain data at a certain file... Is there a way to allocate more memory ? Because my MAX_LINES is already set at 6000.

Comment: What is the input? Make sure the returned pointers are not `NULL` before passing them to the next steps.

Comment: The input is a directory with files. My program read each .json files and print 3 values of these files (I have to take values between commas and after ":").

Comment: If you pass a return value from `fiftylow = strstr(line2, var2);` to `strtok()` which is `NULL` you are fooling `strtok()` to believe that it is a continuation of its splitting process.

Comment: `strtok` does not make copies of the token. Every `fgets` overwrites the line and your tokens. Use `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: `strdup()` is handy if you have access to it, but importantly don't set arbitrary array limits you might smash thorugh. This code is full of rampant duplication which makes it a lot harder to understand than it should be.

Comment: If you're using JSON, where's your JSON parser? Do use a library to do it properly. This code is *extremely* brittle.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you're not stuck using C, this kind of stuff is absolutely effortless in something like Node.js. It's also pretty easy in Ruby, Python, or many other scripting languages that have an easy to use JSON library built-in.

Comment: I can't use JSON parser... I know... Have to do it with standards libraries.

Comment: You'd have to post at least the content of `./data/BLU.json`.

Comment: @Armali the content of this json is too long to post here, but every json file are on one line and every json files have these keys. So in BLU.json : "fiftyTwoWeekHigh":16.68,"fiftyTwoWeekLow":2.7,"regularMarketPrice":5.23
So it seems to doesnt work with regularMarketPrice, but it works for the two others files.

Comment: Not more than 6000 characters have been read from the file. Why do you think 6000 characters were _too long to post here_?

Comment: Even if I change my MAX_LINES variable to like 30000, it stops at the same place. It's like it can't reach more than 3 files.

Comment: That's irrelevant; if the error occurs when _MAX_LINES is already set at 6000_, posting 6000 characters (if there are that many at all) is enough.

Comment: What is `MAX_LINES`? Where is it defined?

Comment: `strtok` may return null if it could not find a token. You don't check for that. Any following function calls may now fail.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie My define MAX_LINES is at the top of my program, before the main function. I tried to add some if conditions to see if my token is null but it shows the same result as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the lines in your file look something like this:

```
{"fiftyTwoWeekLow":32,"fiftyTwoWeekHigh":100, ... }
```

In other words it's some kind of JSON format. I'm assuming that the line starts with '{' so each line is a JSON object.

You read that line into `line2`, which now contains:

```
{"fiftyTwoWeekLow":32,"fiftyTwoWeekHigh":100, ... }\0
```

Note the `\0` at the end that terminates the string. Note also that "fiftyTwoWeekLow" comes first, which turns out to be really important.

Now let's trace through the code here:

```
fiftyhigh = strstr(line2, var1);
fiftyhigh_token = strtok(fiftyhigh, s);
```

First you call `strstr` to find the position of "fiftyTwoWeekHigh". This will return a pointer to the position of that field name in the line. Then you call `strtok` to find the comma that separates this value from the next. I think that this is where things start to go wrong. After the call to `strtok`, `line2` looks like this:

```
{"fiftyTwoWeekLow":32,"fiftyTwoWeekHigh":100\0 ... }\0
```

Note that `strtok` has modified the string: the comma has been replaced with `\0`. That's so you can use the returned pointer `fiftyhigh_token` as a string without seeing all the stuff that came after the comma.

```
fiftyhigh2 = strstr(fiftyhigh_token, s2);
fiftyhigh2_token = strtok(fiftyhigh2, s2);
printf("%s\n", fiftyhigh2_token);
```

Next you look for the colon and then call `strtok` with a pointer to the colon. Since the delimiter you're passing to `strok` is the colon, `strtok` ignores the colon and returns the next token, which (because the string we're looking at, which ends after "100," has no more colons) is the rest of the string, in other words, the number.

So you've gotten your number, but probably not in the way you expected? There was really no point in the second call to `strtok` since (assuming the JSON was well-formed) the position of "100" was just `fiftyhigh2+1`.

Now we try to find "fiftyTwoWeekLow:"

```
fiftylow = strstr(line2, var2);
fiftylow_token = strtok(fiftylow, s);
fiftylow2 = strstr(fiftylow_token, s2);
fiftylow2_token = strtok(fiftylow2, s2);
printf("%s\n", fiftylow2_token);
```

This is basically the same process, and after you call `strtok`, `line2` like this:

```
{"fiftyTwoWeekLow":32\0"fiftyTwoWeekHigh":100\0 ... }\0
```

Note that you're only able to find "fiftyTwoWeekLow" because it comes before "fiftyTwoWeekHigh" in the line. If it had come after, then you'd have been unable to find it due to the `\0` added after "fiftyTwoWeekHigh" earlier. In that case, `strstr` would have returned NULL, which would cause `strtok` to return NULL, and then you'd definitely have gotten a seg fault after passing NULL to `strstr`.

So the code is really sensitive to the order in which the fields appear in the line, and it's probably failing because some of your lines have the fields in a different order. Or maybe some fields are just missing from some lines, which would have the same effect.

If you're parsing JSON, you should really use a library designed for that purpose. But if you really want to use `strtok` then you should:

1. Read `line2`.
2. Call `strtok(line2, ",")` once, then repeatedly call `strtok(NULL, ",")` in a loop until it returns null. This will break up the line into tokens that each look like `"someField":100`.
3. Isolate the field name and value from each of these tokens (just call `strchr(token, ':')` to find the value). **Do not** call `strtok` here, because it will change the internal state of `strtok` and you won't be able to use `strtok(NULL, ",")` to continue processing the line.
4. Test the field name, and depending on its value, set an appropriate variable. In other words, if it's the "fiftyTwoWeekLow" field, set a variable called fiftyTwoWeekLow. You don't have to bother to strip off the quotes, just include them in the string you're comparing with.
5. Once you've processed all the tokens (`strtok` returns NULL), do something with the variables you set.

You may be to pass `",{}"` as the delimiter to `strtok` in order to get rid of any open and close curly braces that surround the line. Or you could look for them in each token and ignore them if they appear.

You could also pass `"\"{},:"` as the delimiter to `strtok`. This would cause `strtok` to emit an alternating sequence of field names and values. You could call `strtok` once to get the field name, again to get the value, then test the field name and do something with the value.

Using `strtok` is a pretty primitive way of parsing JSON, but it will will work as long as your JSON only contains simple field names and numbers and doesn't include any strings that themselves contain delimiter characters.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you mean '\0' ?

```c
if (line[len-1] == '\n') {
  line[len-1] = 0;
}
```

I advise you to use `gdb` to see where the segfault occurs and why.
I don't think you have to allocate much more memory. But the segfault may happens because you don't have anymore data and you still print the result.

Use `if(price2_token!=NULL) printf("%s\n", price2_token);` for example.

Comment: It is meant to be newline as written, although not a robust way of [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) Note that `0` and `'\0'` are the same: an `int` with value 0 although the latter is considered to be clearer in the context of a `char` array.

Comment: I tried but it doesnt change... It is weird, when there's more than 3 files in my directory, it shows a segmentation fault.